# cauchy schwarz inequality on sum of squares

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, inequality

Can I and how I can use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality on the amplitude of a imaginary sum of squares?

$$Z = X+iY$$ and $$|Z| = \sqrt{X^2 +Y^2}$$

to show that $$|E[Z] | \leq \mathbb{E}[|Z|]$$

where $X,Y$ are random variables ?

Comment: This is exactly the same idea as your earlier question about exponentials: the modulus function is convex.  It's worth studying Jensen's Inequality and a proof of it.

Comment: How @AlexR. Can you please help me I don’t know how to do it